# Как сделать правильно запрос Observable?

Tags: angular2, typescript, асинхронность

Изучаю Angular2/TS и возникают вопросы.
Есть служба:`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http'; 
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { IntervalObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/IntervalObservable';

import { Settings} from './settings';
import { GetlocationService } from './getlocation.service';

@Injectable()
export class GetweatherService {
  coordData: any;

  constructor(private http: Http, private _getlocationservice: GetlocationService) {

  }

    getWeatherbyCoordsIntrval(){
        this._getlocationservice.getCurrentPosition().subscribe(
        data => {this.coordData = data}, 
        error => console.log('Error geolocation data'));

        return IntervalObservable
        .create(500)
        .flatMap(() => {
        return this.http.get(Settings.BaseURL+'?lat='+this.coordData.coords.latitude+'&lon='+this.coordData.coords.longitude+'&APPID='+Settings.APPID)
        .map(response => response.json());

     });
    }
}`
```

Всё работает, но как сделать чтобы запрос был не через фиксированные пол-секунды, а по получению координат?

Answer (score 2):

Ну Вы намудрили) нужно использовать `HttpClient`

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private _getlocationservice: GetlocationService) {

  }

  getWeatherbyCoordsIntrval(): Observable<any> {
    return this._getlocationservice.getCurrentPosition()
      .switchMap(data => this.http.get<any>(`${Settings.BaseURL}?lat=${data.coords.latitude}&lon=${data.coords.longitude}&APPID=${Settings.APPID}`))
  }
```

Comment: ошибка ERROR in /angular2-weather/src/app/getweather.service.ts (17,32): Cannot find name 'Subscription'.// Import HttpClientModule from @angular/common/http in AppModule
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';


//in place where you wanted to use `HttpClient`
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; это сделал

Comment: @vladvisitor так ты импортни же `import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';`

Comment: Ок. Сервис ошибку не даёт. Теперь компонент Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'. import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
это я там тоже сделал. Ещё что-то нужно  @Artsiom

Comment: @vladvisitor ну это ты уже решил сделать так в компоненте `getWeatherbyCoordsIntrval().subscribe` верно?

Comment: export class GetplaceComponent implements OnInit {

  weatherData: any[];

  constructor(private _getweatherservice: GetweatherService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this._getweatherservice.getWeatherbyCoordsIntrval() .subscribe(
    data => {this.weatherData = data}, 
    error => console.log('Error fetching weather data'));
  }

}
да. @Artsiom

Comment: @vladvisitor поправил ответ, смотри, убрал подписку и изменил тип возвращаемого значения, теперь будет работать в компоненте

Comment: Всё Ок. Только ещё добавил провайдер и импорт в app.module @Artsiom Спасибо

Comment: @vladvisitor ну да, провайдер само собой, плз ответ пометьте

Answer (score 1):

Замените последние строчки на

```
return Observable
    .create()
    .flatMap(() => {
    return this.http.get(Settings.BaseURL+'?lat='+this.coordData.coords.latitude+'&lon='+this.coordData.coords.longitude+'&APPID='+Settings.APPID)
    .map(response => response.json());
```

Comment: Так не работает. Не читаются данные

Answer (score 0):

Попробую предложить свой вариант:

```
getWeatherbyCoordsIntrval(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((success, pr_error) => {
    this._getlocationservice.getCurrentPosition()
      .subscribe(
        data => success(data),
        error => pr_error(error)
      );
  }).then(
    result => {
       return this.http.get(
        Settings.BaseURL+'?lat='+result.coords.latitude+
        '&lon='+result.coords.longitude+'&APPID='+Settings.APPID
        ).map(response => response.json());
    }
  );
```

В компоненте:

```
someService.getWeatherbyCoordsIntrval().then(
  result => {
    // при успешном выполнении
  },
  error => {
    // при ошибке
  });
```

Comment: у Observable есть метод `toPromise`, поэтому нет нужды использовать конструктор.

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, я ими не пользовался почти, не знал, что есть такой метод у них. С другой стороны это вариант ответа на вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы не ждать фикс. время.

Comment: кстати, очень похоже, что нужно либо убрать `{}` вот тут `result => {` либо добавить `return`: `return this.http.get(` иначе в компоненте result всегда будет Undefined

Comment: @Grundy, не заметил, спасибо.